# MySql Sequelize query to select data from two tables from different database in typescript

Tags: mysql, typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs

### I have two databases `ahuPro` & `workflow`

Tables in ahuPro

- Projects
- CustomerMap -- `'with customerID'`

Tables in workflow

- `Customers` -- `'with PK customerID'`

I created two models for all tables. Inside of the `CustomerMap` model I added `belongsTo` with `Customers` model.

This is my code:

---

##### Query

```
    async findAll(): Promise<Project[]> {
        const projects = await this.projectModel.findAll<Project>({
          attributes: [
            [Sequelize.literal("`Project`.`ProjectID`"), "id"],
            [Sequelize.literal("`Project`.`ProjectName`"), "name"],
          ],
          include: [
            {
              model: CustomerMap,
              attributes: [
                [Sequelize.literal("`Customers`.`CustomerMapID`"), "id"],
                [Sequelize.literal("`Customers->Customer`.`CustomerID`"), "name"],
              ],
              include: [{ model: Customer, association: "Customer", required: false }],
              required: true,
              order: [["CreatedOn", "DESC"]],
            },
          ],
          order: [["CreatedOn", "DESC"]],
        });
        return projects;
      }
```

---

##### Instance in Module

```
    SequelizeModule.forRootAsync({
          inject: [ConfigService],
          name: "workflow",
          useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => {
            const databaseConnection = config.getConfig().DBConnections.workflowDBConnection;
            const connection: SequelizeModuleOptions = {
              dialect: "mysql",
              database: databaseConnection.database,
              host: databaseConnection.host,
              username: databaseConnection.username,
              password: databaseConnection.password,
              // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
              logging: databaseConnection.logging ? console.log : false,
              synchronize: true,
            };
            connection.models = Object.values(workflowModels);
            return connection;
          },
        }),
        SequelizeModule.forRootAsync({
          inject: [ConfigService],
          useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => {
            const databaseConnection = config.getConfig().DBConnections.appDBConnection;
            const connection: SequelizeModuleOptions = {
              dialect: "mysql",
              database: databaseConnection.database,
              host: databaseConnection.host,
              username: databaseConnection.username,
              password: databaseConnection.password,
              // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
              logging: databaseConnection.logging ? console.log : false,
            };
            connection.models = [...Object.values(ahuProModels)];
            connection.define = {
              modelName: "Customer",
            };
            return connection;
          },
        }),
```

---

##### Model

```
    @Table({ tableName: "customermap", freezeTableName: true, timestamps: true })
    export class CustomerMap extends Model<CustomerMap> {
      /**
       * CustomerMapID
       *
       * @type {number}
       * @memberof CustomerMap
       */
    
      @PrimaryKey
      @AutoIncrement
      @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
      CustomerMapID: number;
    
      /**
       * CustomerID
       *
       * @type {number}
       * @memberof CustomerMap
       */
      @ForeignKey(() => Customer)
      @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
      CustomerID: number;
    
      /**
       * Customer
       *
       * @type {string}
       * @memberof Customer
       */
      @BelongsTo(() => Customer)
      Customer: Customer; ///From workflow Database
    
      /**
       * ProjectID
       *
       * @type {number}
       * @memberof CustomerMap
       */
    
      @ForeignKey(() => Project)
      @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
      ProjectID: number;
    }
```

Comment: Its really hard to understand what your expecting from the Stack Overflow community. Its actually hard to even know exactly what your problem is. It sounds like your querying two databases each time you execute a single query?

Comment: Also I hope you format TypeScript better than your Markdown; if you don't then that is likely your issue. Its hard to understand any code base that is a mess. Try using a beautify tool when you author a question, I like this one: https://codebeautify.org/markdown-formatter. It's much easier to author a question in a wide open space that online formatters provide, than it is to author a question in a tiny WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: If I get it correctly AFAIK you cannot make SQL query across two databases by Sequelize. Some DBMSes allow to use remote tables from another DB with limited features but its not about all DBMS and strictly by using raw SQL query (can be executed in Sequelize w/o using models),.